# AWS WebSocket API sometimes not receiving message

Tags: javascript, c#, amazon-web-services, api, websocket

I have a very simple websocket API hosted on AWS.(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-chat-app.html)

I use the websocket to communicate between my Unity project and a website.
If I send this message in Unity then a button on the website will be clickable.
({"action": "sendmessage", "message": "hello"}
My problem is, that sometimes not all clients get the message and sometimes it works perfectly.

Unity - how I send the msg:

```
public void SendMessage()
    {
        var msg = new 
        {
            action = "sendmessage",
            message = "hello"
        };
        _ws.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg));
    }
```

Website:

```
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://xyz.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/x");
```

```
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data == "hello") 
  {
    button.disabled = false;
  }
```

This is my first time working with websockets so thanks in advance for your help.